# Boolean value won't change

Tags: java, boolean

I'm working on a small program that basically just shows that I know how to use superclasses. Everything works great except my boolean value. It's supposed to ask the use of they would like to sign up for the mailing list. If "yes" is entered, the boolean should be true, if "no" is entered it should be false. My problem is that even when I enter "no" it still registers as "yes" making the boolean value true. Please help? (I hope that made some semblance of sense.)

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

public class CustomerDemo 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String name;
        String address;
        String telephone;
        int customerNumber;
        String input;
        boolean mail = false;

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter your name: ");
        name = keyboard.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Enter your address: ");
        address = keyboard.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Enter your phone number: ");
        telephone = keyboard.nextLine(); 

        System.out.print("Enter your customer number: ");
        customerNumber = keyboard.nextInt();

        keyboard.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Do you want to be on the mailing list (Yes or No): ");
        input = keyboard.nextLine();

        if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
            mail = true;
        }

        Customer cust = new Customer(name, address, telephone, customerNumber, mail);

        System.out.println("Hello " + cust.getName() + "!");

        System.out.println("You are customer " + cust.getCustomerNumber() + ".");


        if(mail = false){
            System.out.println("You are not on the mailing list. ");
        }

        else {
            System.out.println("You are on the mailing list. "); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if(mail = false) is a wrong expression.. It should be (mail==false) , Try after changing this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not doing a comparision, you're doing an assignment...

This `if(mail = false)`, equates to `if (false)` because `false` is assigned back to `mail`...

Do `if(!mail)` this instead, which equates to `if (!true)` (or you can also do `if(mail == false)` if you really, really want to)

Comment: That did it. Thank you! Sorry for such a simple question!

Comment: Nice to be of some help :D

Answer (score 2):

look at this line
if (mail = false) this should be if(!mail)

Comment: That did it. Thank you! Sorry for such a simple question!

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong in your reading code.. Error is where you are trying to print. The condition `if(mail = false)` is incorrect.. It should be `if(mail==false)`

Comment: That did it. Thank you! Sorry for such a simple question!